# after used AJAX/GET cannot continue with jq function like .click

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

> i have code with AJAX/GET and after code reload data from php file i
>   have another block code using jquery now my problem its why after
>   reload data from mysql/php server while the page all the date reloaded
>   i can't using function from another script "functionToClick.js". this
>   file with 700 lines and work beutiful wehn i using file without AJAX
>   just normal PHP code. evry one some idee why its like so?

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="style.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleTable.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="contant"></div>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="div_sum"></div>
    <div id="div_list_value"></div>
    <div id="div_list_choice"></div>
    <div id="div_singels"></div>
    <div id="div_singels_value"></div>
    <p></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBets.php",             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
                success: function(response){                    
                    $("#contant").html(response); 
                    /*here i need put my all SCRIPT 
                      from another js file than its work
                      but its lang code ineed include here                       
                      how does i can this*/


                }
            });
        });

        </script>
    <script src="functionToClick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function (){

    var total = 1;
    var value_team = [];
    var sum_value = [];
    var list_value = [];
    var singels = [];
    var singelsvalue = [];
    //var test = 2;

    $("td").on("click", function more()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var choice = $this.attr("choice");
        var value = $this.attr("value");
        var index = 

    singels.indexOf($(this).attr("choice"));
    var a = $this.attr("a");
    var b = $this.attr("b"); 
    var c = $this.attr("c");
    var d = $this.attr("d");
    var e = $this.attr("e");
    var f = $this.attr("f");
    var g = $this.attr("g");
    var h = $this.attr("h");
    var i = $this.attr("i");
    var z = $this.attr("z");
    var idBet = $this.attr("idBet");
    var chaekA = 



$this.next("td").attr("a");
var chaekB = $this.next("td").attr("b");
var chaekC = $this.next("td").attr("c");
var chaekAprev = $this.prev("td").attr("a");
var chaekBprev = $this.prev("td").attr("b");
var chaekCprev = $this.prev("td").attr("c");                                                    
var firstKidsa = $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("a");
var lastKidsa = $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("a");
var firstKidsb = $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("b");
var lastKidsb = $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("b");
var firstKidsc = $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("c");
var lastKidsc = $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("c");
var div_sum = $("#div_sum");
var div_list_value = $("#div_list_value");
var div_list_choice = $("#div_list_choice");
var div_singels = $("#div_singels");
var div_singels_value = $("#div_singels_value");




        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: but its lang code....so match lines...

Comment: Use `on` to attach an event handler. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means. Did you check the link I posted in the first comment?

Comment: the AJAX/GET become one table with data from MYSQL and than with this table wehn user click i miss the function nothing wrong in console F12 by chrome

Comment: ok i mind i have some answer for my problem but i need some code inner my AJAX code after the                                                                      success: function(response){                    
$("#contant").html(response);                                                                              
how does include the script functionToClick.js?

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBets.php",             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
                success: function(response){                    
                    $("#contant").html(response); 
                    //alert(response);
            $( ".with" ).click(function(){
                    $( this ).toggleClass( "with_click" );
                    //$( this ).siblings("th").removeClass( "with_click" );
            });
                                     $( document ).ready(function ()
                                        {

                                            var total = 1;
                                            var value_team = [];
                                            var sum_value = [];
                                            var list_value = [];
                                            var singels = [];
                                            var singelsvalue = [];
                                            //var test = 2;

                                                $("td").on("click", function more()
                                                {
                                                    var $this = $(this);
                                                    var choice = $this.attr("choice");
                                                    var value = $this.attr("value");
                                                    var index = singels.indexOf($(this).attr("choice"));
                                                    var a = $this.attr("a");
                                                    var b = $this.attr("b"); 
                                                    var c = $this.attr("c");
                                                    var d = $this.attr("d");
                                                    var e = $this.attr("e");
                                                    var f = $this.attr("f");
                                                    var g = $this.attr("g");
                                                    var h = $this.attr("h");
                                                    var i = $this.attr("i");
                                                    var z = $this.attr("z");
                                                    var idBet = $this.attr("idBet");
                                                    var chaekA = $this.next("td").attr("a");
                                                    var chaekB = $this.next("td").attr("b");
                                                    var chaekC = $this.next("td").attr("c");
                                                    var chaekAprev = $this.prev("td").attr("a");
                                                    var chaekBprev = $this.prev("td").attr("b");
                                                    var chaekCprev = $this.prev("td").attr("c");

                                                    var firstKidsa = $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("a");
                                                    var lastKidsa = $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("a");
                                                    var firstKidsb = $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("b");
                                                    var lastKidsb = $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("b");
                                                    var firstKidsc = $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("c");
                                                    var lastKidsc = $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("c");




                                                    var div_sum = $("#div_sum");
                                                    var div_list_value = $("#div_list_value");
                                                    var div_list_choice = $("#div_list_choice");
                                                    var div_singels = $("#div_singels");
                                                    var div_singels_value = $("#div_singels_value");

                                    ///////////////////////////////////////////// D 
            /* number 1*/       if(z==1&&a==0&&d==0&&e==0&&f==0)
                                {
                                    sum_value.push(value);
                                    list_value.push(value);
                                    value_team.push(choice);
                                    singels.push(choice);
                                    singelsvalue.push(value);


                                    total *= value;

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("a","1");
                                    $this.attr("d","1");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("d","1");
                                    console.log("number 1 in D");


                                }
            /* number 2*/       if(z=="x"&&b==0&&d==1)
                                {

                                    singels.push(choice);
                                    singelsvalue.push(value);

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("b","1");
                                    console.log("number 2 in D");



                                }
            /* number 3*/       if(z==2&&c==0&&d==1)
                                {

                                    singels.push(choice);
                                    singelsvalue.push(value);

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("c","1");
                                    console.log("number 3 in D");


                                }
            /* number 4*/       if(z==2&&c==1&&d==1)
                                {

                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("c","0");
                                    console.log("number 4 in D");


                                }
            /* number 5*/       if(z=="x"&&b==1&&d==1)
                                {

                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("b","0");
                                    console.log("number 5 in D");



                                }
            /* number 6*/       if(z==1&&a==1&&d==1)
                                {

                                    if (singels.length >= 1)
                                    {
                                    list_value.shift(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.shift(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.shift(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.shift(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);
                                    console.log("yes" + singels.length)
                                    }
                                    total /= $(this).attr("value");
                                    if (singels.length < 1)
                                    {
                                    list_value.pop(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.pop(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.pop(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.pop(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);
                                    console.log("yes 2")
                                    }

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("a","0");
                                    $this.attr("d","0");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("d","0");
                                    console.log("number 6 in D");


                                }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////D sptziel*****************
            /* number 7*/       if(z==1&&a==1&&d==1&&e==0&&chaekB==1&&lastKidsc==0)
                                {

                                    list_value.splice(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.splice(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                //  total /= sum_value.splice(sum_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);

                                    sum_value.push($this.next("td").attr("value"));
                                    list_value.push($this.next("td").attr("value"));
                                    value_team.push($this.next("td").attr("choice"));
                                    singels.push($this.next("td").attr("choice"));
                                    singelsvalue.push($this.next("td").attr("value"));

                                    total *= $this.next("td").attr("value");

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("a","0");
                                    $this.attr("d","0");
                                    $this.attr("e","1");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("d","0");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("e","1");
                                    console.log("number 7 in D sptziel");
                                }
            /* number 8*/       if(z==1&&a==1&&d==1&&e==0&&chaekB==0&&lastKidsc==1)
                                {

                                    list_value.splice(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.splice(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                //  total /= sum_value.splice(sum_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);

                                    sum_value.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));
                                    list_value.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));
                                    value_team.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("choice"));
                                    singels.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("choice"));
                                    singelsvalue.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));


                                    total *= $(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value");

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("a","0");
                                    $this.attr("d","0");
                                    $this.attr("f","1");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("d","0");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("f","1");
                                    console.log("number 8 in D sptziel");

                                }
            /* number 9*/       if(z==1&&a==1&&d==1&&e==0&&chaekB==1&&lastKidsc==1)
                                {
                                    list_value.splice(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.splice(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                //  total /= $(this).attr("value");


                                    sum_value.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));
                                    list_value.push($this.next("td").attr("value"));
                                    value_team.push($this.next("td").attr("choice"));
                                    singels.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("choice"));
                                    singelsvalue.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));


                                    total *= $this.next("td").attr("value");

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("a","0");
                                    $this.attr("d","0");
                                    $this.attr("e","1");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("d","0");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("e","1");
                                    console.log("number 9 in D sptziel");

                                }
            /* number 10*/      if(z==2&&a==0&&e==1&&d==0&&chaekB==1&&firstKidsa==0)
                                {
                                    list_value.splice(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.splice(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                //  total /= sum_value.splice(sum_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);


                                /*  sum_value.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));
                                    list_value.push($this.prev("td").attr("value"));
                                    value_team.push($this.prev("td").attr("choice"));
                                    singels.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("choice"));
                                    singelsvalue.push($(this).parent().find("td:last").attr("value"));
                                */

                                    total *= $this.prev("td").attr("value");

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("c","0");
                                    console.log("number 10 in D sptziel");



                                }

            /* number 27*/      if(z==2&&c==1&&f==1&&d==0&&firstKidsa==0&&chaekBprev==1)
                                {

                                    list_value.splice(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.splice(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                    total /= sum_value.splice(sum_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);

                                    sum_value.push($this.prev("td").attr("value"));
                                    list_value.push($this.prev("td").attr("value"));
                                    value_team.push($this.prev("td").attr("choice"));
                                //  singels.push($this.prev("td").attr("choice"));
                                //  singelsvalue.push($this.prev("td").attr("value"));

                                    total *= $this.prev("td").attr("value");

                                    div_sum.text("Total = " + total.toFixed(2));
                                    div_list_value.html("Selected value = " + list_value.join(", "));
                                    div_list_choice.html("Selected choice = " + value_team.join(", "));
                                    div_singels.html("singels = " + singels.join(", "));
                                    div_singels_value.html("singels_value = " + singelsvalue.join(", "));

                                    $this.attr("c","0");
                                    $this.attr("f","0");
                                    $this.attr("e","1");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("f","0");
                                    $this.siblings("td").attr("e","1");
                                    console.log("number 27 in F sptziel");
                                }
            /* number 28*/      if(z==2&&c==1&&f==1&&d==0&&firstKidsa==1&&chaekBprev==1)
                                {

                                    list_value.splice(list_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);
                                    value_team.splice(value_team.indexOf(+$(this).attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singels.splice(singels.indexOf($this.attr("choice")), 1);
                                    singelsvalue.splice(singelsvalue.indexOf($this.attr("value")), 1);

                                    total /= sum_value.splice(sum_value.indexOf(+$(this).attr("value")), 1);

                                    sum_value.push($this.prev("td").attr("value"));
                                    list_value.push($this.prev("td").attr("value"));
                                    value_team.push($this.prev("td").attr("choice"));

                                }

                                           });

                                    });
                                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: I have collected AJAX if the JS file
Then I just created one file from both files
Thank you all for helping them